# Opensearch not working in magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.6, opensearch

I am new to magento, and I facing a problem with opensearch connection.

I installed magento 2.4.6 in Bluehost, it's working, but then I realized that search for product on the main website is not working, I got this error: [image: No alive nodes found in your cluster]

In the magento backend, I setup the opensearch this way:

```
hostname: 'localhost',
port:'9200',
index_prefix:'magento2',
auth: false,
```

In my env.php file I have this:

```
'open_search' => [
        'enabled' => true,
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '9200',
        'index_prefix' => 'magento2',
        'enable_auth' => false,
        'username' => '',
        'password' => ''
    ],
```

Kindly help me out to fix this problem, if the opensearh settings are not correct, how do I get the proper configuration for it.

I look forward to your help.

Thank you all

Comment: Please try to update your indices alias  at "Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Catalog Search" and run the indexer command, flush the cache.

Answer (score 0):

To verify the status of your OpenSearch engine, follow these steps from the Command Line Interface (CLI), assuming you have SSH access:

Check the status of OpenSearch:

```
sudo systemctl status opensearch
```

Test the connection to OpenSearch:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/"
```

You should see an output similar to the following:

[image: opensearch test result]

If the result differs: Consider restarting OpenSearch with the command:

```
sudo systemctl restart opensearch
```

If the problem persists: Review the OpenSearch logs, which are typically located at:

```
/var/log/opensearch/
```

Check 9200 port on your server, it must be available:

```
netstat -tuln | grep 9200
```

or using `lsof` (it can show who is using this port):

```
lsof -i :9200
```

[image: result of port checking]

If you don't have access to your server via ssh, you can only contact bluehost support. :(

Comment: Thank you for this helps tips, unfortunately, i don't have access to the server, i'd contact bluehost support for help, once again, thank you